# Integrate SonarQube C# ruleset to TeamCity for Code Analysis Build Break

Tags: c#, sonarqube, teamcity, fxcop

Is there someone know here How to integrate SonarQube C# Ruleset in TeamCity for Code Inspection instead using the Resharper(Inspection.NET)?

We don't want to go to sonar site(localhost:9000) to check the C# code issue instead we want to automate this in team city with build break if there is validated rules in C# sonar.

Currently i used FXcop for my Code Inspection but the ruleset from the fxcop is not complete vs from the sonar ruleset for C#, Fxcop contain only the Microsoft Ruleset but not the rulset like in this rule list (bug,pitfall,cwe,convention etc...)

Please help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can launch a SonarQube analysis, and with a web service call look at the quality gate status for example to check that it is not red. If it is red, you are free to make the build fail if you'd like.

However, I personally wouldn't recommend to fail the build, and actually take the habit of going to SonarQube to visualize the quality of your project: It indeed make sense from times to times to introduce some technical debt, however you'll want to make sure that it eventually gets paid back, and that technical debt doesn't grow in every single sprint. Breaking the build when new issues are introduced is like saying that borrowing money should be banned altogether, which is a bit strong.

Comment: Hi Dinesh,  Thank you for your reply but about our automation the management require us to do this because they want to stop our devs to commit their code if they validated the rules in sonar, by the way we are using teamcity plugin in VS 2013(Resharper) to trigger self RUN in TC some feature of this is "commit if success" , that's why we need to break the build in TC if they validated the rules.      and also we already change our plan but same approach i hope you can give me again your feed back regarding this.

Comment: So.... what we do right now is to deactivate all Sonar C# rules and Activate only the Fxcop rules in our "Sonar Way" but our problem now is we have Error in TC Sonarqube runner:                                                                                                                             
  
[12:34:47][Step 5/7] ERROR: Unrecognized option: Files                                           originally the first error is

Comment: "The property "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly" must be set and the project must have been built to execute FxCop rules. etc..........."    then i add this line of code in the "Add parameter"          -Dsonar.cs.fxcop.fxCopCmdPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop"                                        
    then new error display [12:34:47][Step 5/7] ERROR: Unrecognized option: Files.

Comment: these are the list of Add parameter value in our sonar                                                                                                                              
  -X -Dsonar.cs.fxcop.fxCopCmdPath = C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Team Tools/Static Analysis Tools/FxCop/FxCopCmd.exe

-Dsonar.visualstudio.enable=true
-Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

Comment: -Dsonar.resharper.solutionFile="%teamcity.build.workingDir%\HelloWorld.csproj"
-Dsonar.resharper.cs.reportPath="%teamcity.build.workingDir%\resharper.Hello.World.results.xml"
-Dsonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths="%teamcity.build.workingDir%\HelloWorld_%teamcity.build.id%.html"